# batch using 7zip compresses more files in one archive instead of more files in more archives

Tags: batch-file, cmd, 7zip

i have a .bat file that uses 7zip for compressing. It creates an archive for every single file in a folder. It works both with win 2003 or win 2008.

Here's my problem:

on a new server win 2008 based, it compress every file in one single archive.

Here the script:

`for %%X in (*) do "C:\TOOLS\7zip\App\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "%%~nX.zip" "%%X"`

Any suggestion?

Comment: It won't `compress every file in one single archive.`  Test it again in a folder with a bunch of text files.

Answer (score 1):

You might like doing as below...

```
for /d %%x in (D:\Your_folder_path\*.*) do "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -tzip "%%x.zip" "%%x\"
```